# How to write simple routes in PHP

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, url-routing

I'm working on a project using [Cloud9 IDE](https://c9.io/), running PHP5 on Apache 2.0. I'm primarily a front-end developer, but I have decent experience with PHP. I'm familiar with MVC frameworks, and to a lesser degree, this functionality is what I'm trying to emulate, but simpler. I tried implementing CakePHP, but found it was a little too robust for what I needed -- I don't want a backend-heavy setup. I want to write some custom sort of routing mechanism for my application.

Ideally, I would like every request to my site to come through one page (this custom "Controller"), and from there I can write my own logic to figure out the appropriate templates, http codes, errors, etc., to include. My question is, how do I make this happen? In other words, how do I make a request to `http://mysite.c9.io/user/view/2` get channeled through `http://mysite.c9.io/index.php` , and not try to request the `/user/view/2` directory on my server?

I'm vaguely familiar with `mod_rewrite` and .htaccess rules, but I suspect they may play a role here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure that `mod_rewrite` is enabled. Check your `httpd.conf` file for

```
 LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Make sure it's not disabled with a `#` in front of it. Next change the root `<Directory>` settings to

```
<Directory />
  Options All
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Make sure you change all the occurrences of `AllowOverride None` to `All`. Then restart Apache.

Now that `mod_rewrite` is enabled, add this to an `.htaccess` file in your web root `/` directory

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # not a dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # not a file
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

This makes sure that every request that otherwise would have been a `404` (which means it excludes images, css, js etc.) now routes through the front controller `index.php`. Some, content management systems like to add another `%{REQUEST_URI}` check to make sure `index.php` is only invoked to process the kind of requests the framework actually expects.

`Joomla`, for example, adds the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf))$ [NC]
```